# Can i use HTML5 history in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, modernizr, html5-history

[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) clearly says that IE8 and IE9 does NOT support HTML5 History, however if i emulate IE8 in Microsoft Edge developer tools, and check with modernizr:

```
if(Modernizr.history) {
    alert("History is available");
} else {
    alert("History is NOT available");
}
```

I get that history IS actually available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulation is not a reliable way to test things. You should try using the real browser, from something like SauceLabs and browserstack, or using one of the free VMs from https://modern.ie

To answer your question - no.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Emulation is not the same as actual IE 8, this might be the cause
I suggest to set up virtual machine with IE8 and check yourself.